# Can you include Jquery Theme with a URL

Tags: jquery-ui-theme

Like this!

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url "http://www.jquery.com/path_to_jQuery_theme.css";
</style>
```

Is something like this possible?  Or do I NEED to download it to be able to include it?

Answer (score 0):

NVM, found it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
```